# Delete stacktrace of wrapper exceptions: bad idea?

Tags: java, logging, exception, error-handling

When logging a wrapped exception, you usually get a long stacktrace about the wrapper, then a few lines of the actual root cause if there's room.  But the root cause is the exception whose stacktrace I want to read!

I am wrapping most exceptions in my app in custom exceptions that I control. (Reasoning for this in the background below.) To solve this logging problem, is it reasonable to have my custom wrapper exceptions simply delete most of their stacktrace upon construction?

If I remove most of the stacktrace in my wrappers as they are constructed, everything is logged beautifully: log4j seems to print n lines of log about an exception and its causes, and truncating the stacktrace of my wrappers to 1 element makes room for plenty of stacktrace about the root cause.

I can't think of any situation where I would want to know anything more than maybe the first line of trace, but something just bugs me about removing stacktrace information.  I'm inexperienced, and I can't sort out if my intuition is right or if I'm just uncomfortable with an unusual situation.  Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with this?

**Background if it's relevant**:

I am trying to figure out a reasonable first pass at decent errorhandling in a large java webapp.  My current plan is to wrap exceptions in a custom exception when they occur, then let them bubble up to the top level where they are logged. (I would like to use my custom wrapper to attach a unique ID to every exception I see, so I can propagate that ID up to the UI and easily find the relevant logs even long after the fact.)

This is a followup question closely related to [When to log chained exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282993/when-to-log-chained-exceptions), where I was worried about how to log chained exceptions so that I get more info about the actual cause than a bunch of useless stacktrace about subsequent wrappers.  One of the suggestions-- not chaining through all the layers but letting exceptions bubble up to a top layer where I can control the logging -- is reasonable, and as long as they get to the top level it's easy to put code in one place to log the root cause, instead of the wrapper.  But if I ever have cause to catch and log one of these exceptions, I'm stuck with the default logging behavior again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop stacktraces truncating in logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437756/how-do-i-stop-stacktraces-truncating-in-logs)

Comment: Totally not a duplicate of the linked question. OP is asking if its a good idea to delete the stack traces, not how to do it.

Comment: @Perception: OP wants to delete the stacktrace of wrapper exceptions so the entire stacktrace of the root cause is logged. Rather than help him with his (misguided) approach, the linked question shows how he can accomplish his ultimate goal.

Comment: I disagree. The question you linked is regarding the 'xxx more lines' that show up in (some) log files. Nowhere does that author express an interest in deleting stacktrace or displaying only root exceptions in a log file. This is ***not*** a duplicate question of that.

Comment: @meriton thanks for the reference! But the solution(?) proposed in that question doesn't really satisfy me. (I assume you are referring to the second answer suggesting using ExceptionUtils.printRootCauseStackTrace().) I'm interested in letting my logger do my logging, so printing to stderr is not appealing.  Even if I was okay with that, I don't want to change the logging behavior for exceptions that aren't instanceof my custom wrappers, so my logging code would have to look different based on the type of exception I want to log-- yuck.

Comment: Meta: Assuming I find a solution to my problem that ISN'T misguided, would it be bad etiquette to post a new question with a more general title so that others can easily find it?  I'm finding ways to control how loggers express throwables that would be relevant under a question titled "Good way to log wrapped exceptions?" but are unrelated to deleting stacktraces, even though they help with the root cause (ha ha) of my reason for asking this question.

Comment: @Perception: OP wrote: "you usually get a long stacktrace about the wrapper, then a few lines of the actual root cause if there's room. But the root cause is the exception whose stacktrace I want to read!".

Comment: @PotataChipz: I thought that "101 more lines" in the stacktrace might have misled you to think the stacktrace was incomplete, but that feature only hides *redundant* information, as the edit in the linked question, and its accepted answer describe. Did I guess wrong, i.e. are you observing a different truncation?

Comment: @meriton Ah, I see what you mean.  I should have read that question more carefully.  Even though the information is all complete in my logs, I would rather see only the root cause, or the root cause first.

Answer (score 1):

That "... 101 more lines" in the stacktrace does not mean that the stacktrace is incomplete, as that feature only hides redundant information. For more details, see the edit and accepted answer of the following question:

[How do I stop stacktraces truncating in logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437756/how-do-i-stop-stacktraces-truncating-in-logs)

As for your follow-up question:

> Even though the information is all complete in my logs, I would rather see only the root cause, or the root cause first.

As far as I know, log4j delegates stack trace rendering to Throwable.printStackTrace, which does not allow customizing the format. However, its sucessor [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) can write stacktraces with the root cause at the top.